# How to convert JSON array objects to Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

How do I convert from JSON array objects to Kotlin?

### Format from JSON to Kotlin

---

```
 "company": {
54: {
"id": "54",
"type": "metan",
"region_name": "Urganch shahri",
"open_close": 1,
"name": "Xorazm IDEAL GAZ",
"image": "https://metan.mbos.uz/persons/145787891644148634.jpg",
"start_time": "00:00",
"end_time": "23:59",
"price": "2600",
"orientr": "Obl.GAI ko'prik o'ng tomonida",
"googlemap": "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=41.530320,60.649560&ll=41.530320,60.649560&z=16"
},
56: {
"id": "56",
"type": "metan",
"region_name": "Xonqa tumani",
"open_close": 1,
"name": "Shaxzodbek Sulaymon",
"image": "https://metan.mbos.uz/persons/5634558381644152414.jpg",
"start_time": "00:00",
"end_time": "23:59",
"price": "2500",
"orientr": "Oxunbabayev. ShoxOil",
"googlemap": "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=41.491009,60.748586&ll=41.491009,60.748586&z=16"
},..57..58..59..60
```

---

1. The main problem is object would be an increase

---

please give me a solution or link where I will found solution

Comment: Can you post what you have tried to do this?

Comment: I have tried to do it with Map Interface but it's not working, I have used JSON Kotlin Formatter Plugin but it's actually not working it was statically working, but I want this, I want it is dynamic

Comment: Post Your map interface code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "JSON To Kotlin Class ​(JsonToKotlinClass)​" plugin for Android Studio. This plugin coverts existed JSON to data classes.

How use this plugin you can find [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-).

How add plugin to your Android studio you can find [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-uninstall-plugins-in-android-studio/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Open%20the%20Android,Plugins%20in%20the%20left%20panel.).

Comment: Please see the main problem below

Comment: Create a model class for the inner object like in 54, 56, After that get value in hashmap which has key (Int) and value (Inner object model).